# Elegant way to test that new objects are created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm building a very basic test to check if an object is created in a relationship. `Website has_many languages`. I've the method `add_language` that receives an array of ids and adds them.

This is some of my tests:

```
  describe '#add_languages' do
    subject{ build(:website) }

    it 'return nil if no language is added' do
      expect(subject.add_languages []).to be_nil
    end
    it 'adds one single language' do
      languages_ids = [Language.last.id]
      original_count = subject.languages.count
      subject.add_languages languages_ids
      expect(subject.languages.count).to eq(original_count + languages_ids.count)
    end
    it 'adds multiple languages' do
      languages_ids = Language.limit(3).pluck :id
      original_count = subject.languages.count
      subject.add_languages languages_ids
      expect(subject.languages.count).to eq(original_count + languages_ids.count)
    end
 end
```

What I don't like is

1) The code is duplicated
2) I don't like using `eq` for this, but not sure how to use other matchers

What would be an elegant way to write those tests?

Comment: Can you just define a function inside of the describe that receives an array of language_ids? This way you can reuse the code by simply calling the function. I'm 99% sure ruby and ROR will let you do this.

Answer (score 0):

Two quick ways you can do this: add a helper method, or add a loop.

**Helper Method**

```
it "adds on single language" do
  check_creates_languages([Language.last.id])
end

it "Adds multiple languages" do
  check_creates_languages(...)
end

def check_creates_languages(language_ids)
  original_count = ... # etc
end
```

**Loop**

```
[1,3].each do |language_count|
  it "can add #{language_count} language(s)" do
    original_count = Language.last(language_count).count
    # etc
  end
end
```

Also, there's nothing wrong with using `eq`, that's what it's there for. What else would you want to use? You could also use `be`.

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can do:

```
expect{subject.add_languages languages_ids}.to change{Language.count}.by(1)
```

More or less (based on your use case).